# Hot to get PDFBox 1.5 .Net Version dlls?

Tags: lucene, pdfbox

I have troubles with certain PDFs when indexing for Lucene (System.NullreferenceExceptions).

I figured out that there is a new version (1.5.0) is available we work currently with 0.7.3, but how do i get the .dll for .net?

Thanks in advance

Dirk

Answer (score 2):

You can build the .NET version of PDFBox yourself as described [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/building.html).

Or you can grab unofficial binaries:

- [1.8.x](http://www.squarepdf.net/pdfbox-in-net)
- [1.7.0](http://pdfbox.lehmi.de/)
- [1.2.1](http://www.antoniob.com/pdfbox-121-for-net-binaries.aspx)
- [0.8](http://www.blacklocustsoftware.com/PDFBox_Binaries.php)